# Yammers bug Access-Control-Allow-Origin error again

Tags: yammer

I have my site added to the white list, all worked fine until yesterday, when I started to get XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.yammer.com/platform/login_status.json?client_id=[xxx]&_=1408773433021. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
As I remember there was such bug already couple of moths ago, can anybody fix it on yammer side?

Comment: This sounds like a Yammer bug. I work there and I'll report this so we can look into it. But please don't report bugs here. Stack overflow is for questions about integration code. We have a separate support channel for bugs.

Comment: Where should I post bugs?

Comment: See the links at the bottom here. To be clear, this has been updated recently. We realized that we weren't being clear about what goes on SO. https://developer.yammer.com/yammer-developer-network/

Comment: Also, your issue may be related to this one, which was fixed recently. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480700/request-header-field-yammer-capabilities-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow