# Request header field yammer-capabilities is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Tags: yammer

Our API requests have started failing with the error "Request header field yammer-capabilities is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers".

Before the weekend, everything was working correctly.
Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about This is really a Yammer support request and not a question that can be solved in it's current state.

Comment: A fix for this went in last night.  As others have said - SO isn't really for bug reports, but it worked out well this time.

Comment: Reagan, I notice that it's working again in Chrome, but not always in Internet Explorer. In IE10 (browser mode IE10, document mode standards) it's not working. When I change the document mode to IE9 standards, it's working correctly. Do you know why?

Comment: I get the following error: SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here, but it is not the first time, and I think we shouldn't change anything: Yammer's API is slowly beginning to be migrated to Office365's API, maybe this is why there is so much errors in this API... (hope so!)

If you want to see what they're working on :
https://about.yammer.com/success/engage/grow-your-network/release-schedule

Btw, did you try to post this issue on [yammer](/questions/tagged/yammer) Developer Network ? This can really help, they are using there own social network to communicate ;)

Comment: yammer reps don't seem to be responding here or there...:(

Comment: https://developer.yammer.com/new-changes-on-the-ydn-yammer-developer-network/ it's now the correct way to ask on SO with the #yammer tag